# Expand a div to fill the remaining width

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I want a two-column div layout, where each one can have variable width e.g.

```css
div {
  float: left;
}

.second {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>Tree</div>
<div class="second">View</div>
```

I want the 'view' div to expand to the whole width available after 'tree' div has filled needed space.

Currently, my 'view' div is resized to content it contains
It will also be good if both divs take up the whole height.

---

**Not duplicate disclaimer:**

- [Expand div to max width when float:left is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017880/expand-div-to-max-width-when-floatleft-is-set)
  because there the left one has a fixed width.
- [Help with div - make div fit the remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727012/help-with-div-make-div-fit-the-remaining-width)
  because I need two columns both aligned to left

Comment: Either I don't understand the question or I don't understand how you choose the accepted answer, because there both widths and heights are fixed with the inconvenience of `overflow hidden`

Comment: @user10089632 It is the correct explanation for the behavior, and at the time better solutions like flexbox were not available.

Answer (score 1090, accepted):

The solution to this is actually very easy, but not at *all* obvious.  You have to trigger something called a "block formatting context" (BFC), which interacts with floats in a specific way.

Just take that second div, remove the float, and give it `overflow:hidden` instead.  Any overflow value other than visible makes the block it's set on become a BFC.  BFCs don't allow descendant floats to escape them, nor do they allow sibling/ancestor floats to intrude into them.  The net effect here is that the floated div will do its thing, then the second div will be an ordinary block, taking up all available width *except that occupied by the float*.

This should work across all current browsers, though you may have to trigger hasLayout in IE6 and 7.  I can't recall.

**Demos:**

- Fixed Left: http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/5/
- Fixed Right: http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/2/

```css
div {
  float: left;
}

.second {
  background: #ccc;
  float: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>Tree</div>
<div class="second">View</div>
```

Comment: What if the content is big enough to overflow the div ?

Comment: This doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome with none div elements set to `display:block`.

Comment: good answer. but why isn't the same principle valid to "float: right"?

Comment: @Andrade It is valid, if by that you mean "can I use float:right for the sidebar instead?". Totally still works.  If you mean "why can't I just use float:right for the main area", it's for the same reason float:left doesn't work - it shrinkwraps the content.

Comment: If I take-out all css from ```.left``` other than ```height```, it still takes-up all remaining width. If I change ```display``` to anything other than ```block``` it doesn't work. (Firefox 34.0)

Comment: No overflow needed, Just put the variable-length div in the last (so it will be computed lastly). See https://jsfiddle.net/wangzhihao/A8zLY/2258/

Comment: Incorrect. Without 'overflow' (or some other means of triggering a BFC), the variable-length div won't "avoid" the other div.  Its *text* will avoid the floated divs, but its background/border/etc will encompass them, which probably isn't what's wanted.

Comment: It is important to note, that the order of the children matters. The floating element with fixed width has to be above the other one. Took me too long to figure out, why it didn't worked for me with switched order.

Comment: I wrote an answer explaining why a non-visible overflow of all things triggers a BFC, based on responses given by David and Boris, which can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943503/why-does-css2-1-define-overflow-values-other-than-visible-to-establish-a-new-b/11854515#11854515 Was my interpretation correct?

Comment: Is there a way to make both columns always the same height and valign the content? http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/3334/

Comment: Yes, use Flexbox. Floats were never meant for this sort of layout, they were just a required hack before Flexbox (and now Grid) existed to do it correctly.

Comment: the "fixed left" fiddle has the .left box on the right and the .right box on the left, which is pretty confusing at first. :P

Comment: when the flexible part is an input, it won't work, even when setting it to display:block, any ideas?

Comment: An updated tweak on your fiddle using flexbox, which allows you to have this behavior without having to specify exact widths: http://jsfiddle.net/xseoa9rk/

Comment: The link for "the magic of overflow" is no longer valid, the new one is https://colinaarts-com.herokuapp.com/articles/the-magic-of-overflow-hidden

Comment: Doesn't work if container has width:100% !

Answer (score 185):

I just discovered the magic of flex boxes (display: flex). Try this:

```
<style>
  #box {
    display: flex;
  }
  #b {
    flex-grow: 100;
    border: 1px solid green;
  }
</style>
<div id='box'>
 <div id='a'>Tree</div>
 <div id='b'>View</div>
</div>
```

Flex boxes give me the control I've wished css had for 15 years. Its finally here! More info: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you. Can you please explain why do you have `flex-grow: 100;` instead of `flex-grow: 1;`?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev No particular reason except that's how I like to do it. It allows me to think in percents so if I could do something like set #a to `flex-grow:10` and then I'd set #b to `flex-grow: 90` so #a would be 10% of the line's width and #b would be 90% of the line's width. If no other elements have a flex width style, then it doesn't technically matter what you put.

Answer (score 70):

Use the [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) `flex-grow` property to fill the remaining space.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
}
.second {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div style="background: #bef;">Tree</div>
<div class="second" style="background: #ff9;">View</div>
```

Answer (score 29):

This would be a good example of something that's trivial to do with tables and hard (if not impossible, at least in a cross-browser sense) to do with CSS.

If both the columns were fixed width, this would be easy.

If one of the columns was fixed width, this would be slightly harder but entirely doable.

With both columns variable width, IMHO you need to just use a two-column table.

Comment: Table won't be very good in a responsive design where you want the right hand column to slide under the left on small devices though.

Comment: There are some responsive design tricks to work with tables: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: I tend now to often design two separate layouts completely and change  on a mobile using media queries and `display:none;` Whilst making as much as possible 100% responsive on a sliding scale sometimes it's nicer to change your design completely for a mobile making use of the touch screen feel and button style.

Answer (score 25):

Use `calc`:

```css
.leftSide {
  float: left;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
.rightSide {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:200px">
  <div class="leftSide">a</div>
  <div class="rightSide">b</div>
</div>
```

The problem with this is that all widths must be explicitly defined, either as a value(px and em work fine), or as a percent of something explicitly defined itself.

Comment: The benefit of this is that it works with input type fields, which the top rated comment wont.

Answer (score 22):

Check this solution out

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.content {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 200px;
}
.item {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: blue;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
  <div class="sidebar">width: 200px</div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="item">25%</div>
    <div class="item">25%</div>
    <div class="item">25%</div>
    <div class="item">25%</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is generally a superior solution because hiding overflow is not always desired.

Comment: Per OP: "I want a two-column div layout, where each one can have variable width".  In your answer, you have to know the width of the first column, so it's not variable.  You might as well set fixed widths on both columns and just float them.

Answer (score 16):

Here, this might help...

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    div.box {
      background: #EEE;
      height: 100px;
      width: 500px;
    }
    div.left {
      background: #999;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
    }
    div.right {
      background: #666;
      height: 100%;
    }
    div.clear {
      clear: both;
      height: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 0pt;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="left">Tree</div>
    <div class="right">View</div>
    <div class="clear" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: +1 because your example seems to work, but in my real scenario some how contents from 'view' creep into 'tree' div, as tree div is not 100%, may be some javascript forces it to be small and after height of tree I see view contents

Comment: In that case, if u know the max-width of the left column, u can either give it a style max-width (does not work in IE) or think of margin-left (beware of double-margin bug on IE) or padding-left.

Answer (score 9):

If the width of the other column is fixed, how about using the [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) CSS function [working for all common browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility):

```
width: calc(100% - 20px) /* 20px being the first column's width */
```

This way the width of the second row will be calculated (i.e. remaining width) and applied responsively.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand why people are willing to work so hard to find a pure-CSS solution for simple columnar layouts that are SO EASY using the old `TABLE` tag.

All Browsers still have the table layout logic... Call me a dinosaur perhaps, but I say let it help you.

```html
<table WIDTH=100% border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=2>
  <tr>
    <td WIDTH="1" NOWRAP bgcolor="#E0E0E0">Tree</td>
    <td bgcolor="#F0F0F0">View</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Much less risky in terms of cross-browser compatibility too.

Comment: yes, but if everything is being done by css why not this, at least a curiosity if it is possble?

Comment: That is because if you want to put `media-queries` to put both columns one above the other in small devices, it is impossible with the old `table` tag. To get this working, you need to apply `CSS` table styles. So, for nowadays it is better to solve this with `CSS` if you want a responsive layout for any screen size.

Comment: Because tables are for tabular content. OP doesn't have tabular content; they have two divs with unknown content inside of them.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    div.box {
      background: #EEE;
      height: 100px;
      width: 500px;
    }
    div.left {
      background: #999;
      float: left;
      height: 100%;
      width: auto;
    }
    div.right {
      background: #666;
      height: 100%;
    }
    div.clear {
      clear: both;
      height: 1px;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 0pt;
      margin-top: -1px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="left">Tree</div>
    <div class="right">View</div>
    <div class="right">View</div>
    <div style="width: <=100% getTreeWidth()100 %>">Tree</div>
    <div class="clear" />
  </div>
  <div class="ColumnWrapper">
    <div class="Colum­nOne­Half">Tree</div>
    <div class="Colum­nOne­Half">View</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I want something like a status bar with fixed items on the left, fixed items on the right and one message line that uses all of the left over space.
I started with this answer and added my message div AFTER the floats with:

height: 20px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow:clip

Answer (score 3):

You can try [CSS Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

```css
dl {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content auto;
}

dt {
  grid-column: 1;
}

dd {
  grid-column: 2;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>lorem ipsum</dt>
  <dd>dolor sit amet</dd>
  <dt>carpe</dt>
  <dd>diem</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 3):

flex-grow - This defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion. It dictates what amount of the available space inside the flex container the item should take up.

If all items have flex-grow set to 1, the remaining space in the container will be distributed equally to all children. If one of the children has a value of 2, the remaining space would take up twice as much space as the others (or it will try to, at least). See more [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
}

.child {
  flex-grow: 1; // It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion
}

.left {
  background: red;
}

.right {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"> 
  <div class="child left">
      Left 50%
  </div>
   <div class="child right">
      Right 50%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In your exemple both divs will grow and fill the remaining space. The question asked that one div doesn't grow, and the other fills the remaining space.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different implementation,

Two div panels(content+extra), side by side, `content panel` expands if `extra panel` is not present.

jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/qLTMf/1722/

Answer (score 1):

You can use W3's CSS library that contains a class called **`rest`** that does just that:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-row">
  <div class="w3-col " style="width:150px">
    <p>150px</p>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-rest w3-green">
    <p>w3-rest</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Don't forget to link the CSS library in the page's `header`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
```

Here's the official demo: [W3 School Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_grid_rest&stacked=h)

Comment: Looks like that just adds "overflow: hidden", which makes it a worse version of the answer already given

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is the answer you are expecting but, why don't you set the width of Tree to 'auto' and width of 'View' to 100% ?

Comment: Because that will put the second float below the first because it's too wide.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btnCont {
  display: table-layout;
  width: 500px;
}

.txtCont {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 70%;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-width: 20%;
}

.subCont {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 80%;
  min-width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="btnCont">
  <div class="txtCont">
    Long text that will auto adjust as it grows. The best part is that the width of the container would not go beyond 500px!
  </div>
  <div class="subCont">
    This column as well as the entire container works like a table. Isn't Amazing!!!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no html reference for the css class .ip and it doesn't work in IE7

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a javascript function that I call from jQuery $(document).ready(). This will parse all children of the parent div and only update the right most child.

html

```
...
<div class="stretch">
<div style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; display: inline-block;">Some text
</div>
<div class="underline" style="display: inline-block;">Some other text
</div>
</div>
....
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    stretchDivs();
});

function stretchDivs() {
    // loop thru each <div> that has class='stretch'
    $("div.stretch").each(function(){
        // get the inner width of this <div> that has class='stretch'
        var totalW = parseInt($(this).css("width"));
        // loop thru each child node
        $(this).children().each(function(){
            // subtract the margins, borders and padding
            totalW -= (parseInt($(this).css("margin-left")) 
                     + parseInt($(this).css("border-left-width")) 
                     + parseInt($(this).css("padding-left"))
                     + parseInt($(this).css("margin-right")) 
                     + parseInt($(this).css("border-right-width")) 
                     + parseInt($(this).css("padding-right")));
            // if this is the last child, we can set its width
            if ($(this).is(":last-child")) {
                $(this).css("width","" + (totalW - 1 /* fudge factor */) + "px");
            } else {
                // this is not the last child, so subtract its width too
                totalW -= parseInt($(this).css("width"));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy using flexbox. See the snippet below. I've added a wrapper container to control flow and set a global height. Borders have been added as well to identify the elements. Notice that divs now expand to the full height as well, as required.
Vendor prefixes should be used for flexbox in a real world scenario since is not yet fully supported.

I've developed a free tool to understand and design layouts using flexbox. Check it out here:
http://algid.com/Flex-Designer

```css
.container{
    height:180px;
    border:3px solid #00f;
    display:flex;
    align-items:stretch;
}
div {
    display:flex;
    border:3px solid #0f0;
}
.second {
    display:flex;
    flex-grow:1;
    border:3px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Tree</div>
    <div class="second">View</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you read ALL the previous answers before adding yours? it seems no ...

Comment: as a side note, you don't need to add `stretch` because it's the default value and no need to make the child element flex container so `display:flex` is useless for the inner elements

Comment: I wonder why the downvote, without any comment. Isn't this answer replying to the question? Why? If trying to help others is penalized I will think twice before my next answer,

Comment: you got two comments after the downvote, it's not enough?

Comment: Temari, Did you check out my tool? Don't you think is useful and could help others? Do you think is not related with the question? Where is your answer to this question? I can't see it. What's your role here?

Comment: sorry but an answer is not dedicated to promote you own tools, the answer should answer the question and actually the flexbox answer is already provided twice here so there is no need to repeat it

Comment: The free tool is one reason among others that make me downvote this question and I gave those reasons, if you want to ignore them you are free ... your answer is already provided twice so you didn't even check the previous answers and your code contains useless things. I could have downvoted and leave without adding any comments but I did the effort to do so because I care about the quality of the site.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.resize_overflow {
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  word-wrap: normal;
    /* text-overflow: ellipsis; When the end of the line dissolves, the ellipsis loses */
}
.second_fix {
    float: right;
    /* or:
    display: flex;
    align-self: end;*/
}
/* Dissolve the end of the line at the right edge */
.resize_overflow::after {
    content: ""; /* Empty content */
    position: absolute; /* Position relative to parent */
    right: 0; /* Element position */
    top: 0; /* Element position */
    width: 40px;  /* Gradient width */
    height: 100%; /* Parent Height */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.2), #ff 100%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.2), #ff 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.2), #ff 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255, 0.2), #ff 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255, 0.2), #ff 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="resize_overflow">Tree</div>
    <div class="second_fix">View</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the available CSS layout frameworks. I would recommend [Simpl](http://simpl.romack.net/) or, the slightly more complex, Blueprint framework.

If you are using Simpl (which involves importing just one *simpl.css* file), you can do this:

```
<div class="Colum­nOne­Half">Tree</div>
<div class="Colum­nOne­Half">View</div>
```

, for a 50-50 layout, or :

```
<div class="Colum­nOne­Quarter">Tree</div>
<div class="Colum­nThreeQuarters">View</div>
```

, for a 25-75 one.

It's that simple.

Comment: will both columns be variable width?

Answer (score -6):

If both of the widths are variable length why don't you calculate the width with some scripting or server side?

`<div style="width: <=% getTreeWidth() %>">Tree</div>`

```
<div style="width: <=% getViewWidth() %>">View</div>
```

Comment: How does the server know how the client's layout engine will work?

Comment: Simple: develop it for 90% of the browsers out there :)  IE 7+ , FF3+ and Safari support CSS 3.  You could also include the standard IE6 <!--[if lte IE 6]> element.  By the way, what browser doesn't support style="width: %" ??

Comment: I don't know how It can be done server side, but yes some javscript may do it but i want to avoid it unless css/html can't do it

Comment: Which it can't.  Therefore, if you want both to be dynamic then you have to do it in either script or server side.