# Variable width div between fixed width div and hidden/visible div

Tags: css, html

```
<div id="d1">
  <div id="d2">label</div>
  <div id="d3"><input name="t1" id="t1" type="text" /></div>
  <div id="d4">Message</div>
</div>
```

- `#d1` and `#d2` has fixed width.
- `#d4` can be displayed or hidden (`visibility: visible;` or `visibility: hidden;`). When it's visible, it has fixed width.

I want that `#d3` have a variable width, so it can fill the remaining right space of `#d1` when `#d4` is hidden, but when `#d4` is visible, fill the space between `#d2` and `#d4`.

How can achieve this using CSS?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to stretch the width of an element, so that it is (100% - widths of its siblings)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682649/how-to-stretch-the-width-of-an-element-so-that-it-is-100-widths-of-its-sibl)

Comment: @Wex - Close, but I still need the div on the right side.

Comment: Alright, I posted [a modified version of that answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12701713/522877).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with something that slightly alters your HTML structure:

```
<div id="d1">
    <div id="d2">label</div>
    <div id="d4">Message</div>
    <div id="d3"><input name="t1" id="t1" type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

​CSS:

```
input { width: 100%; }
#d2 { 
    float: left; 
    display: inline-block; }
#d4 { 
    float: right;
    display: inline-block; }
#d3 { 
    padding: 0 10px; 
    overflow: hidden; }
​
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/HLME4/

Comment: Thank you very much, I ended doing this way. However, it doesn't work as expected using "visibility: hidden;", but it does using "display: none;", because using the visibility property seems that the div is still there, but just not visible. Should I edit the question to mention the "display" property instead of the "visibility" property?

Comment: Nah, I think your question is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the following CSS would achieve what you're shooting for:

```
#d1 {
    display: table; 
}

#d2, 
#d3, 
#d4 {
    display: table-cell; 
}

#d2, 
#d4 {
    width: (the width you want); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I wish I could mark two answers as valid. I didn't marked this because of compatibility with IE7 and older (http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout), although I didn't mentioned it as a condition.