# Expand div to take remaining width, with nice source order

Tags: css

This question is basically a fork of [Expand div to take remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/), with a crucial difference: I want the columns to have different source and display orders.

Source order:

```
<div class="view">View</div>
<div class="tree">Tree</div>
```

Display order:

```
------------------
| Tree | View    |
------------------
```

Restrictions:

- `.tree` has variable-width content; it should shrink to its content, while `.view` takes up the remaining width.
- Columns will have variable heights, too, so there's no room for negative `margin-top` trickery.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UrXdw/

Is this possible to do in pure CSS?  Target browsers are modern browsers and IE8+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several approaches to this problem, and my conclusion is that it's **not possible**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why the left column is flexible, but in that case I don't think you will have any luck doing it without javascript.

Comment: `.tree` will contain a nested-`ul` tree representation.  The `li`s' contents will be text.  It's flexible to accommodate (and shrink-to-fit) whatever text is put in it (potentially up to a `max-width` if necessary, but so far it's not necessary).