# Making a div expand to available width, alongside an h1/h2 tag

Tags: css, html

Here's a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/cKuUy/2/

---

Here's a screenshot of what I'm aiming for:

[image]

And what I'm getting in my browser:

[image]

The key difference is that in the actual implementation, the bars do not fill the available width of the containing div element. If I place: `width:100%`, the bar expands to it's container width, but goes down, below the text; despite both elements being floated left.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767270/1472586

Basically remove `float: left` and `width` from the bars and add `overflow: hidden` to them. You may also have to adjust your margins accordingly (right padding on the headings might work better, for example).

Comment: Worked like a charm! I had to add `padding-right:5px;` to both h1 and h2 elements, but it's working great now. Thanks!