# Filling the available space with display:table-cell

Tags: html, css, displaytag, tablecell

Is it possible to avail the second div to occupy the available space of the parent div without specifying manual width?

Here is the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JqHXJ/2/) for the tried demo.

```
.right_cnt {
    display: table-cell;
    background:#FFC;
}
```

***NOTE***: I need yellow box to occupy the available right space.

Comment: from your fiddle it looks like it already occupies the avaiable space on the right, and it doesn't look like you've maunually specified width anywhere

Comment: Is this is the thing you need : http://jsfiddle.net/JqHXJ/3/ OR this : http://jsfiddle.net/JqHXJ/4/ OR this : http://jsfiddle.net/JqHXJ/5/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `display:table; width: 100%;` on the parent element, remove `float: left` from the sibling.
http://jsfiddle.net/byNpM/2/

Comment: I didn't find any difference. I need that yellow box to occupy the available right part

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use table layout to do this, but it's not necessarily the easiest way: [forked your fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/8MyFv/).

An easier way is to modify the second cell to remove all table display properties and set the second element's `overflow` to `hidden`: [another fork demonstrating this](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/8MyFv/2/). `zoom: 1` allows the technique to work in old IE. This might be simpler for your purposes, if you're happy with the side-effects of the `overflow`

Comment: "Forked your fiddle"... crikey.

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width) might might be what you are looking for.

In particular look at [Xanthir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767270/703717):

> The solution to this is actually very easy, but not at all obvious.
>   You have to trigger something called a "block formatting context",
>   which interacts with floats in a specific way. ... ...

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that, while `display:table-cell` on the last div in a row with no `width` will cause it to stretch to fill the enclosing parent `display:table` div, the table-cell has an implicit 'min-width' behaviour that can't be turned off, forcing it to be the width of its child.

I had to resort to absolute-positioning the left cell on top of a wide padding on a 100% wide right cell.  With this, the 100% wide inner div shrinks as required when the window is narrowed and the content scrolls.

http://jsfiddle.net/kmbro/cqkzbc4a/

Comment: I should have read Danield's answer - putting float:left on the left div and overflow:auto on the right does the trick!  Fiddle updated to demonstrate.