# 100% input text, a button next to it - how?

Tags: html, css

I want to do the following

```
(we are inside a fix width div)
<input text><img>
```

if I set 100% width to the text, the img goes newline.

EDIT: I tried:

```
<div style="width: auto;">
<input style="width: 100%; float: left;" />
</div>
<img style="float: right;" alt="smiles" src="a.gif" width="21" height="21" />
```

Comment: Why are you setting the input to 100% width?

Comment: because I want it to be as wide as the inner container MINUS image width

Comment: this is what I cant tell to CSS

Comment: 95% would be fit, but what if the container is wider?

Comment: Then set 95% to input, and 5% to image.

Comment: Refugnic Eternium, I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<div>
    <img style="float:right;" src="a.gif" />
    <input style="width: 100%; display:block;" />
</div>
```

What this code does: It floats the image to the right of the block in question.
The `display:block;` makes the input a block element, which will pay attention to the float above (an inline-element would not care about it).

BTW, I took this solution from here: [Expand a div to take the remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width)

Comment: still no joy, img goes newline

Comment: @user1929946 Okay, I found a better solution. I tried it and it works as desired (if I got you right).

Comment: the inputfield overlaps the image :D

Comment: I could've sworn...try adding `overflow:hidden` please. Which browser are you using?

Comment: @user1929946 Do you have a link where I could look at your version of the page? Because you see, for me it works just fine (though Opera gives me funky results)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27279/discussion-between-refugnic-eternium-and-user1929946)