# Strange HTML/CSS Issue

Tags: html, css

I know that it has been asked tons of times, but I'm still not able to find a fix for this issue. Here is what I have this: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cVGK6/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="container" style="width:auto">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#FFA500;">
<h1 style="margin-bottom:0;">Main Title of Web Page</h1></div>

<div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:100%;width:auto;float:left;">
<b>Menu</b><br>
HTML<br>
CSS<br>
JavaScript</div>

<div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:100%;width:auto;float:left;">
test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content test content </div>

<div id="footer" style="background-color:#FFA500;clear:both;text-align:center;">
Copyright © something</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem us that the content is going under the menu. I tried everything in order to fix it, but it seems imposible. I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something small.

EDIT: The content should be next to the menu and the menu shuld have 100% height

Comment: wgat do want exactly?

Comment: The content should be next to the menu and the menu shuld have 100% height I have edited the question. :)

Comment: There is a problem with `width:auto`. It works with an hardcoded number. [See this jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/kmWHF)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `float:left` on the content , replace it with `overflow:auto`

This triggers a `block formatting context` and causes the content to fill the remaining horizontal place. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767270/703717) post.

Updated [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5PE8c/1/)

Comment: Ok, but I need the footer of the bottom of the page. I mean that if the content is empty the page should not be changing. Now the footer is going up and everything seems to be messy. :( I also tried `bottom:0;` without success

Answer (score 0):

add `position:absolute;` to `id="menu"`  and `height:auto`

```
#menu{
background-color: #FFD700;
height: auto;
width: auto;
float: left;
position: absolute;
}
```

[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/cVGK6/4/)

or if you want it next to menu than this [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/cVGK6/6/)

where you remove `float` to `id="content"`

Answer (score 0):

use a parent div to menu and content, give it style `overflow:hidden`

Then give some width to the menu say `20%` and `float:left`
And to content give `float:right` and width `80%`

I have updated your jsfiddle link.. It showing proper result