# html and js rectangle resizing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am developing a photo collage just like this one  [1]: http://www.fotor.com/features/collage.html but i am making it using javascript and html the issue right now i am facing is that i want to resize the rectangle dynamically. Dynamically i mean if i resize any of the rectangle the others will get resize as well so can any one help or suggest me any solution ? or any lib of js ? or if anyone have done can share it ?

```
if (newSide != UNKNOWN) {
    if (ndiv.resize(newSide, deltaX, deltaY)); { //
        this.resizeNeighbours(newSide, ndiv, deltaX, deltaY);
        calls.push({
            d: ndiv,
            n: newSide,
            dx: deltaX,
            dy: deltaY
        });
    }
} //end if new side unknown 
} //end 
for
for (i = 0; i < calls.length; i++) {
    c = calls[i];
    this.autoSizeDivs(c.n, c.d, c.dx, c.dy, dep + 1);
}
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: Please include some example code.

Comment: if(newSide != UNKNOWN){
    
     if(ndiv.resize(newSide, deltaX, deltaY));{
      //this.resizeNeighbours(newSide, ndiv, deltaX, deltaY);
      calls.push({d: ndiv, n: newSide, dx: deltaX, dy: deltaY});
     }
    
   }//end if new side unknown
  }//end for
  
  for(i=0; i < calls.length; i++){
   c = calls[i];
   this.autoSizeDivs(c.n, c.d, c.dx, c.dy, dep+1);
   
  }
  }catch(e){console.log(e);}
  return true;
 }

Comment: @WaleedAhmed Please use the [edit link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18445936/edit) under your question, and add the code into the question body.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f8DY8/28/
and take a look at this post: [Expand a div to take the remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width)

```
<style>
.rec{
    border:1px solid #249fea;
    margin:3px;
}
.container
{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
</style>


<button id="changeWidthBtn">Change Width</button><br/>

<div class="container">
    <div style="float:left;width:100px;height:200px;" class="rec" id="one">one</div>
    <div style="overflow:hidden;height:50px;" class="rec">two</div>
    <div class="rec" style="overflow:hidden;height:150px;">three</div>
</div>


<script>
$("#changeWidthBtn").click(function(){
    $("#one").width("200px");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post but if you open the link then you will see that the height and width of all rectangles are not same just like [link] http://www.fotor.com/features/collage.html

Comment: I think i understand you problem, you what to resize the collage but keep the same ration between the pics?

Comment: not exactly ratio but parent remain the same and child get resize have you check the link  ?

Comment: So you want to resize one photo and have all the other photos somehow fill the remaining space?

Comment: yes i want this thing to be happen i will be very thank full if you can help me out

Comment: whats about height ? as i am trying to do it using the mouse

Answer (score 0):

You can give each row a CSS class then, with the help of jQuery, get all images in the row using a CSS selector. You then call your resize function on each selected DOM element.

Comment: Thanks for the post but if you open the link then you will see that the height and width of all rectangles are not same just like [link] fotor.com/features/collage.html