# css positioning like a grid

Tags: html, css, position

So I am stuck on this seemingly easy problem:

I want my page to be made up of two sections. First is a nav-bar on the left that is **always 300px**. Next is the content of the page, which should fill the rest of the space to the left.

Both of these elements have `position:relative`

Let me explain this with code:

```
#navBar{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#666;
    width:300px;
}
#content{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#999;
    /* what can I put here to make it so, no matter 
    ** what (even on resize), the div this represents
    ** will always go from the end of #navBar to the
    ** end of the entire window?
    */
}
```

I know I will probably have to use `float:left` somewhere in here, but I still need to get the width right before I can use `float`

If I wanted to use jquery, I could do:

```
var ww = $(window).width();
$("#content").width(ww-300);
$(window).resize(function(){
    ww = $(window).width();
    $("#content").width(ww-300);
});
```

but I was hoping this was doable in css...

any ideas?

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sX4Ys/)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `float: left` for the `navbar`. No need for `position: relative`

```
#navBar{
    float: left;
    background-color:#666;
    width:300px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sX4Ys/1/)

If the content div might be longer than the `navbar` and you don't want it to flow below the navbar, you can add a `margin-left`

```
#content{
    background-color:#999;
    margin-left: 310px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sX4Ys/4/)

Comment: thanks!! that worked perfectly. I'll accept the answer when I am allowed

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/GvC4k/1/

I thought you might like the menu 100% height as well.

```
 body,html{height:100%; font-family:Arial;}
.menu{float:left; width:300px; background:#dadada; height:100%;}
.content{background:#888888;}
```