# How to extend divs?

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
     <div class="first">Example</div>
     <div class="second">
         <div class="inner"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

"wrap" have width (100% or 1000px)

"inner" have height and border-bottom

I want to expand "first" and "second" like this

```
|==================== 1000px or 100% ======================|

Example_____________________________________________________
```

If I add width to "first" and "second" it looks fine:

```
|==================== 1000px or 100% ======================|

Example_____________________________________________________
```

but if Example text change to longer it wraps:

```
|==================== 1000px or 100% ======================|

Another_____________________________________________________
Example
and
text
```

But if "first" and "second" have no width "second is invisible:

```
|==================== 1000px or 100% ======================|

Example
```

How to do it?

EDIT:

from this:

[Expand a div to take the remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width)

It works, example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.box { background: #EEE; height: 100px; width: 500px; }
div.left { background: #999; float: left; height: 100%; width: auto; }
div.right { background: #666; height: 100%; }
div.clear { clear: both; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; font-size:0pt; margin-top: -1px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">
   <div class="left">Tree</div>
   <div class="right">View</div>
   <div class="clear" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. Could you expand on the last two lines?

Comment: Is this what you need http://jsfiddle.net/8d3ZV/1/

Comment: edited post - examples

Comment: @Nips Forget `But if...`s. Say what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for min-width:

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/min-width/

Which will set a minimum width without making that width the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need.

```
overflow:auto; and a max-height
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2hFs5/

Comment: but they are not next to each other (chrome)