# Layout div to fill remaining width from another div with auto width

Tags: html, css, layout

I would like 2 divs side by side with a fixed height.

The first is an image and I want to set the width to auto so the image is proportionally correct.

The second div I want to fill the remaining space. How do I do this?

Comment: Tried this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width

Comment: Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aVVHU/