# Css center element with relative width

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have this setup:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uq46e/18/

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="a">1</div>
    <div class="a">2</div>
    <div class="a">3</div>
    <div class="x"></div>
    <div class="a">5</div>
    <div class="a">6</div>

</div>
```

I want div class x to occupy remaining width (wrapper minus other elements). Parent wrapper needs to stay responsive.

Is it possible with just css?

edit:

updated the question (all elements are left floated)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand div to take remaining width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width)

Answer (score 0):

You could use calc attribute on your css width rule:

```
width: calc(100% - 250px);
```

250px is the amount of all your other widths.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Uq46e/15/)

Here's a solution that mimic's CSS calc so that it is usable in IE8:

```
$('.x').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=250px');
```

[JSfiddle with Javscript](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Uq46e/24/)

Comment: 1. It needs to work on all browsers, 2. I cannot have defined width for div x because some of the elements left or right of it might be removed.

Comment: not possible without JS / JQuery. You're going to have to calculate the widths of the other items and then do something like $('.x').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=250px'); http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Uq46e/24/

Answer (score 0):

Add below given class and then check

```
.x {
background: green;
width: calc(100% - 250px);
height: 50px;
float: left;
}
```

I tested it on your fiddle.

Comment: No calc, it needs to work on all browsers (from ie8)

Comment: Then you need jquery to handle it because display:table-cell has cross browser compatibility issue and display:inline-block; doesn't work on IE7