# Floated elements rendering differently in Chrome/Firefox when triggering a "block formatting context"

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

Chrome and Firefox are rendering floated divs differently and I can't figure out a solution.

**Chrome** (left window): The div expands to fit the entire string "123456" when sitting next to the blue square

**Firefox** (right window): The div cuts off part of the string

[image: Chrome (left), Firefox (right)]
**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/A8zLY/83/

For reference, I'm using a technique to trigger the BFC "block formatting context" described here: [Expand a div to take the remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width)

The technique allows a div element (the red text) to fill the remaining width of the container when placed along a static width element (the blue square)

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="module1">
    <div class="container left">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">123456</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container left">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">123</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="module2">
    <div class="container right">
        <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">123456</div>
    </div>
     <div class="container right">
         <div class="icon"></div>
        <div class="text">123</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
}
.text {
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 50px;
    background: red;    
}
.left .icon { float: left; }
.left .text {
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.right .icon { float: right; }
.right .text {
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

.module1, .module2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border: 4px solid black;
}
.module1 { left: 0; }
.module2 { right: 0; }
.container { margin: 4px; }
```

Comment: which one you want??? as chrome or firefox? in the fiddle...

Comment: Chrome's implementation is preferred

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the left/right margin equal to the width of `.icon` on the `.left .text` and `.right .text` classes:

```
.left .text {
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.right .text {
    width: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xN43L/

Comment: This works. I am curious however why Firefox behaves this way without the hack.

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure I can explain it, just seems to be a difference in the way Firefox and Chrome render the result. Floating .icon takes it out of the document flow, as .text isn't floated it's kind of oblivious to .icon so setting the margin just ensures that the space it takes up is accounted for.