# Update size of 100% width element

Tags: jquery, html, css

i've got the following problem.

I have this page structure:

```
<body>
    <nav></nav> // position absolute, width 300px
    <main></main> // position relative, width 100%
 </body>
```

[image: Layout]

The main element lays over the nav. I've got a jquery function to open the nav which pushes the main to the right. 
But the main element is going out of my body to nowhere instead of staying 100% width. This is quite logicaly because the body didn't change.

How can i structure my layout to achieve that the main element acts responsive to the changes?

Here is the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9td4cf03/

Comment: Can you please provide jsfiddle with code samples?

Comment: When you open nav you can subtract nav width to main width.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand div to take remaining width](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width)

Comment: Must `main` definitely remain at `width:100%` all the time? If you don't want it to be 100% you shouldn't set it to be 100%.

Comment: I've added jsfiddle. :)

Comment: @Rhumborl: it should be responsive and not going outside the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the liberty of simplifying your HTML and CSS as follows.

One approach is to use absolute positioning to move your `nav` block and its content out of
the flow.

The `.st-main` block is stacked over the `nav`.

When you click the button, you can make the `nav` visible by expanding the left margin of the
`.st-main` block.  This will work quite well with CSS3 transitions.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("button").on('click', function () {
         $(".st-main").toggleClass('expand');
     });
 });
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.st-container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
.st-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: beige;
}
.st-main {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
    transition: margin-left 0.5s ease-in-out;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.st-main.expand {
    margin-left: 300px;
}
button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="st-container">
    <button>Click</button>
    <nav class="st-menu">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li>First stuff</li>
            <li>Second stuff</li>
            <li>Third stuff</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <main class="st-main"></main>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly and is very easy. :)

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use `box-sizing` on your main element (or possibly on everything). This will make the `padding` value included within the overall `width` value. Effectively it will allow you to give it a `width:100%;` and then give it a `padding-left:300px;` and the 300px will be subtracted from the 100%.

CSS:

```
*,
*:before,
*:after { /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements; see http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/ */
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Not needed for modern webkit but still used by Blackberry Browser 7.0; see http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing */
    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box; /* Still needed for Firefox 28; see http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing */
    box-sizing:         border-box;
}
```

You can either apply this to everything via the `*` like I have shown, or just apply it to the main. I recommend applying it to everything if your site is not to complicated yet.