# Center align background images between list items

Tags: html, css

I'm building a responsive website which has a standard navigation. Each `<li>` element has a background image, [like so](https://jsfiddle.net/j0c1w162/):

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    background: url(http://bit.ly/1D60g6m) no-repeat 68% 0;
    background-size: 10%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
            <li>Six</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

My `background-position` roughly aligns the background image to the middle of each `<li>`.

As you reduce the viewport width, the image is no longer aligned to the middle. This is more noticeable when I use different background images for each `<li>`.

Is there a better way I can align the background image to the whitespace between each `<li>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some reading from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width), I've come up with an [alternative solution](https://jsfiddle.net/84a0xahd/1/).

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">One</a><div></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a><div></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a><div></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">Four</a><div></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">Five</a><div></div></li>
            <li><a href="#">Six</a><div></div></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
}
li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
li div {
    min-height: 20px;
    background: url(http://bit.ly/1wxK23y) no-repeat center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This method means you don't need to use `text-align: center;`. Positioning the image to the right and aligning the list text to the center is a good solution, but it becomes a problem if your navigation needs to align with the body content.

I'll leave this answer unsolved for 24 hours to see what you think.

Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `background-size` from `10%` to `contain`

```css
.container {
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    width: 100%;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: left;
    background: url(http://bit.ly/1D60g6m) no-repeat 68% 0;
    background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
            <li>Six</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0c1w162/5/)

Comment: Thanks buddy. I'm not using `background-size` in the real version. This is to simply reduce the size of the arrow image that I grabbed from Google.

Answer (score 1):

Moving the image to the right and centering the list text would seem to be the most likely option.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  float: left;
  width: 16%;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(http://bit.ly/1D60g6m) no-repeat 0;
  background-size: 10%;
  background-position: right center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>One</li>
      <li>Two</li>
      <li>Three</li>
      <li>Four</li>
      <li>Five</li>
      <li>Six</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: It's important that the text is aligned to the left, so this isn't really an option for me. Good suggestion though :)

Comment: Good answer !  I think it is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/j0c1w162/7/

```
<div class="container">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
            <li>Six</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

.container {
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    width: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;

}
li:after{
    background: url(http://bit.ly/1D60g6m) no-repeat 68% 0;
    background-size: 20%;
    content: '';
    width: 50px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -18px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: It's important that the text is aligned to the left, so this isn't really an option for me. Good suggestion though :)