# Css default width with min-width but grown to fit content

Tags: css

I have a container that I want to have a `min-width` of `250px` and a default width of `500px`. However, if the content inside of it becomes bigger than `500px` I want it to grow to fit that content.

How do I do this?

Here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/e0uo7w8n/

```css
.e
{
    font-size:20px;
}
.viewport1, .viewport2
{
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:#000000;
    border-style:solid;
    padding:20px;
}
.viewport1
{
    width:300px;
}
.viewport2
{
    width:800px;
}
.root
{
    background-color:#FFCCCC;
    min-width:400px;
    max-width:600px;
    padding:20px;
}
.colFixed
{
    background-color:#CCFFFF;
    width:200px;
    float:right;
    height:150px;
    padding:20px;
}
.colFluid
{
    background-color:#FFCCFF;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport1">
    <p class="e">Viewport 1: Demonstrates min-width</p>
<div class="root">
    <div class="colFixed"></div>
    <div class="colFluid">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/20x150">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
    
<div class="viewport2">
    <p class="e">Viewport 2: Demonstrates default width</p>
<div class="root">
    <div class="colFixed"></div>
    <div class="colFluid">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x150">
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    
<div class="viewport2">
    <p class="e">Viewport 2: But it should resize to the picture</p>
<div class="root">
    <div class="colFixed"></div>
    <div class="colFluid">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/400x150">
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I confess I'm struggling to see a use case for this.

Comment: I have a container with two columns. One is a fixed width float, the other takes up the rest of the space. By setting the parents container width I can set the width of the column that fills the rest. This also shinks when the page is smaller. I want a min width so it doesnt get too small. A default width so it doesnt get too big on big screens but not a max width so that if it needs to get bigger on big screens it can.

Comment: That's a very odd way try to make it responsive. That's what media queries are for.

Comment: Perhaps this is more what you are trying to do - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-div-to-take-remaining-width

Comment: Im using that technique to make the one div take the remaining width. But to resize it, I'm changing the width of the parent container as described above. I think media queries might be the way to go. I dont know the width of what I'd need to set it to unless I checked the width of every child in the column

Comment: added snippet for example

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to remove the `width:500px`so the div could grow with content and add `max-width` to limit it as your needs and set your min-width to 500px to use it as default width with media-query for smaller screen. I could help you more if you'll add some code.

Comment: Ill add a fiddle, give me a sec