# Inline divs with one having custom width

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code two inline Divs, one has defined width *in px value* while the other get the rest width of the container

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">main</div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar (300px)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so what's your question?

Comment: Could you post the CSS that you've tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-a-div-to-take-the-remaining-width?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't really give us much to go on, but I would suggest using `display:table-cell;` instead of `inline-block`.

```css
.wrapper {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.main, .sidebar {
  display:table-cell;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.sidebar {
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">main</div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar (300px)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [CSS table layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) as its super-easy to implement and has [really good support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table). It also has the added benefit of balanced column heights - thus making columned layout a doddle to create.

```css
html, body {min-height:100%; height:100%; margin:0;}
.wrapper {display:table; width:100%; height:100%; min-height;100%;}
.wrapper .main {display:table-cell; background:#eee;}
.wrapper .sidebar {display:table-cell; background:#666; width:300px;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">main</div>
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar (300px)</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

using calc without floats:

```css
body,
div {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 0
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.main {
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc( 100% - 300px);
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar (300px)</div>
</div>
```

this is kind of fragile , table or flexboxes are better_

---

flexbox example:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

.main {
  flex-basis:300px;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
}

.sidebar {
  flex:1;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">main</div>
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar (300px)</div>
</div>
```