# In two-column layout, make one column have fixed width and the other take remaining space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way I can set the right hand panel to be say 200px and for the left panel to take up the rest of the space?

At the moment the right panel appears under the left panel.

Also, if I change the parent width, the left and right panels should appear within the parent and be sized accordingly.

```css
#left {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 180px;
  margin-left: 190px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260122/expand-a-div-to-take-the-remaining-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flexbox:

```css
#container {
    display: flex;               /* establish flex container */
}

#left {
    flex: 1;                     /* consume all available space */
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

#right {
    flex: 0 0 180px;             /* don't grow, don't shrink, fixed at 180px width */
    background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/20bj8o8v/)

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).*

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can set the right hand panel to be say 200px and for the left panel to take up the rest of the space?

**Yes.**

There's a variety of ways you can implement it. I have listed four options below. The first three will require the use of [`width: calc(100% - 200px)`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) for the left panel. The last option using [flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) does not require it.

**Using `position: absolute`:**

```css
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

#right {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using `display: inline-block`:**

```css
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

}

#left {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

#right {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div><!--
--><div id="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using `float`:**

```css
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;

}

#left {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

#right {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

**Using `display: flex`:**

```css
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#right {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #00FF00;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div id="left">
    left
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Swap DIVs around to change processing order:

```
 <div>
   <div id="right">
    right
</div>
<div id="left">
    left
</div>

 </div>

  <style>
  #left {
     background-color:#ff0000;
 }
 #right {
    float: right;
    width:180px;
    margin-left: 190px;
   background-color:#00FF00;
}
  /style>
```

Answer (score 0):

That kind of layouts can be easily addressed by using Flexbox, other option is to use `calc`, which browser support isn't too wide, but could help... you'll need to add:

```
#left {float: left; width: calc(100% - 200px);}
```

That's assuming your other element will be 200px per your question (but not your code), please remove the `margin-left` from the element `#right` to make this work.

Hope this helps.

If you want to check browser support for `calc`, take a look to http://caniuse.com/#search=calc