# div to fill gap between a left floated and right floated div

Tags: css

I have the following html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="leftside">left</div>
  <div id="middle">middle</div>
  <div id="rightside">right</div>
</div>
```

and the following css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container {
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
}
#container div {
  height:50px;
}
#left {
  float:left;
}
#middle {
  float:left;
  background-color:red;
  text-align:center;
  width: fill_the_gap_between_left_and_right_div_regardless_of_their_widths
}
#right {
  float:right;
}
```

How do I specify the width of the middle div so that it fills the gap between the left and right divs?

Comment: You can't do that with `float` as far as I know. `flexbox` would be a better option here.

Comment: This is being flagged as already having an answer, but that answer is only 2 divs and does not work in this case.  How would the flex approach look?

Comment: The flexbox approach is given in the link [Expand a div to fill the remaining width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40447261). The middle div is given `flex:1` so it takes up the remaining width.

Comment: Cheers Paulie_D. I made the mistake of only looking at the most popular answer and the question only mentioning 2 divs.  flex did the job :)